# robot_pose_ekf timing error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting the error:

```
ERROR: filter time older than vo message buffer
```

when I run only the Kinect through openni_launch -> fovis -> robot_pose_ekf

I am aware that this issue is caused by "two sensor inputs have timestamps that are not synchronized" as referenced by
http://ros.org/wiki/robot_pose_ekf/Troubleshooting

My questions are:

1.) I am only using the vo message topic from fovis. Are the errors possibly because the depth and rgb cameras are out of sync?

2.) How can I correct this issue? I am aware of approximate and exact time message filters and fovis implements both.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58173/robot_pose_ekf-timing-error/) by [ee.cornwell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4115/ee.cornwell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2013-03-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-14**:
Is everything running on the same machine? 1) seems very unlikely as both message should have been produced by the same driver.

**Comment by [ee.cornwell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4115/ee.cornwell/) on 2013-03-14**:
yes, everything is running from the same machine.  I'm only feeding it Kinect data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have another topic going into robot_pose_ekf?  (such as /odom?)  It requires at least two topics in order to function.  Otherwise, there's no need to filter only one topic.  :)

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1